# Jetpack Compose: how do you animate size increase of a child elment by factor of n

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

Say I have a composable with a button. I want to know how I can animate the button to change size by a factor of n given that the button is/isn't focused. Currently, I have this:

```
@Composable
fun someButton() {
  Column() {
    Button(
      modifier = Modifier
        .onFocusChanged { buttonFocusState ->
          if (buttonFocusState.isFocused) {
            // TODO: Increase button size by, lets say 1.2X current size of button
          } else {
            // TODO: Set button size back to 1X its size (original size)
          }
        }
        .animateContentSize(
          animationSpec = tween(../) 
        )
    ) {
      ../
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I have most of this setup, but I am failing to grasp how I can easily store the inherent size of the button (after it is drawn) without recomposition and then take that value and do something like increase it by a factor of 1.2.

I've looked into methods like Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {}, but read that would trigger a recomposition. I know there's .onSizeChanged{} or just .size(), but all of these require you to set/know the buttons size. What I really need to know is how do I store the buttons Size as, I assume, a mutable state variable, so I can play with that size. All while keeping recompositions down to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested. I hope it works for you:

```
@Composable
fun SomeButton() {
val onFocusSizeChange = remember { Animatable(1f) }
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

Column {
    Button(
        onClick = {},
        modifier = Modifier
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                size = it.size
            }
            .size(
                height = (onFocusSizeChange.value * size.height).dp,
                width = (onFocusSizeChange.value * size.width).dp
            )
            .onFocusChanged { buttonFocusState ->
                if (buttonFocusState.isFocused) {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        onFocusSizeChange.animateTo(
                            1.2f,
                            animationSpec = tween(500, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing)
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        onFocusSizeChange.animateTo(
                            1f,
                            animationSpec = tween(500, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
    ) {
        //
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did see the .onGloballyPositioned modifier in other answers but also read it causes unneccessary recompositions. So, wouldn't this answer be a bit unfitting?

Comment: It seems that you have no other choice, unless you set the button size. Then you don't need to use .onGloballyPositioned to get the button size.